# Calculating mode in a grouped frequency distribution

Tags: statistics

How can I calculate the  mode in a grouped frequency distribution when the  largest frequency occurs in two or more classes?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried when the largest frequency happened in two different classes, then what is the  mode? Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

If the you have a frequency distribution where the largest frequency occurs in two or more classes, then we call it a [multimodal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution). For example, if you set of data is $\{1,1,1,2,2,3,4,7,7,7,8\}$, the mode would be both of the values $1$ and $7$.

Comment: I know this.  But my question is related to grouped data.

Comment: If you don't know what the original data is and you only have the classes that the data fall into, then you can't say anything about the mode among the individual data points. There is only a mode among the classes ("*the mode of this grouped frequency distribution would be class ... and class ... .*").